# Connecting 3 Li-ion pouch cells in series with BMS

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, lipo, bms

I have three 2000 mAh, 3.7 V Li-ion pouch cells.

I want to connect these three cells in series to get 11.1 V and 2000 mah

[image]

I made 11.1 V out of three Li-ion cylinder cells before; I used a BMS.

[image: bms]

As my project now needs a small, compact battery, I want to DIY a 3s, 11.1 V Li-ion battery pack with pouch cells.

Can I connect the Li-ion pouch cells in series with a BMS to get 11.1 V, in the same way as with the Li-ion cells?

If yes, can I use a block adapter to recharge it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you connect three Li-po cells with the same capacity and at the same state of charge, and use a 3S balancing BMS, you can build a good and safe battery pack. You can't just connect a power supply for charging, though. You will still need a proper 3S Li-po charger to charge the battery pack; the BMS is not a charger.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second picture is [this amazon battery protection board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J9NXQ6W), it should work with Li-Po Cells as well as cylinder cells.

[image]

As @orcdu says, you will need a separate charger. Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B092LCYDQW) should work, however you will need to get a [3s balance connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TXYL61V) to connect the individual cells to the balance output. Connect the output to P+ and P- of the BMS and wire the balance connector like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you call "Lipo" are actually Li-ion cells in a pouch package. Internally, they are Li-ion cells regardless of whether they are housed in a plastic pouch or a metal cylinder. Therefore, as long as they have the same voltage (in this case, 3.6 V nominally), they work the same regardless. That BMS will work with them the same, because, whether they are housed in a plastic pouch or a metal cylinder, these cells act the same.